# Pass Query String Value into jQuery Ajax Call in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a webMethod with a single argument I am trying to call via jQuery Ajax. Now the argument is supposed to be the query string of the url in which I am making the ajax call. I don't know how to pass the query string as an argument into the method from the jQuery ajax. My Code is as follows

**C# Method**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string FollowUser(string userId)
{
   //Code to follow user
   //returns a string value

}
```

**jQuery Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnFollow").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/FollowUser",

                    data: //how do I pass the query string here 

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", datatype: "json",
                    context: this,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        //I'm doing some stuff here
                        }

                    },

                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Someone help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data as part of the the URL or change the method to GET. When submitting an aJax post with data you are sending the data as part of the request body (form data). This won't be as a query string attribute but part of the content. Instead change the URL To include the data. Example.

```
Default.aspx/FollowUser?userId=user1
```

changing to a GET method will force the post parameters to be part of the query string instead.

Comment: Thanks @Nico for your response. But actually userId isn't always constant. It changes based on user profiles selected in the application. How then can I properly set the query string and include it in the URL as you have illustrated? Thanks again.

Comment: Change your URL dynamically to fit the data before the Ajax call or change to a GET method. Either way posting directly to the content body WILL send it in the post body. For the query string it MUST be part of the URL. Remember a GET request will always put the values into the URL however this also means that the values are in the URL and are transparent.

Comment: I'm really sorry that your answer may be right but I'm not quite understanding what I need to do here. I changed POST to GET and changed my url to `Default.aspx/FollowUser?userId=` but don't know what to put as the value. Can you please illustrate your explanation via code? thanks.

Comment: In "?userId=..." After the equal you will put the string you are trying to pass as a parameter in your "public static string FollowUser(string userId)" method. So let's said you want to send "foo" to the method, you will to this "Default.aspx/FollowUser?userId=foo". Hope that helps.